# Соединить таблицы + в одной таблице соединить ряды

Tags: php, mysql

Всем добрый день,

Есть несколько таблиц, к примеру:

**таблица товаров**

```
id          shop_id    item_name        item_qty    
 1           100       coca-cola         2           
 2           100       pizza             1         
 3           101       cheeseburger      5           
 4           102       pepsi             4
```

**покупателей**

```
     id          shop_id    email           
     1           101       test@test.ru                    
     2           102       test@test.ru                      
     3           103       test@test.ru                 
     4           104       test@test.ru
```

**статусы покупок**

```
         id          shop_id    status_st           
         1           100       not_cheked                    
         2           101       not_cheked                      
         3           102       not_cheked                 
         4           103       not_cheked
```

**информация покупок.**

```
         id          date        summa          method           
        100        2017-02-09     10$            bank        
        101        2017-02-09     10$           i-bank          
        102        2017-02-09     10$            bank     
        103        2017-02-09     10$            bank
```

Мне нужно объеденить их примерно следующим образом:

```
 id          date        summa          item_name           status_st    email
100       2017-02-09      10$       coca-cola, pizza        not_cheked  test@test.ru
```

Чтобы товары с одинаковыми ID соединялись в одну строку и плюс ко всему объеденить с другими таблицами.

Я пробовал следующим образом:

```
SELECT s.id, s.date, s.summa, s.method, s.language, b.email, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(it.item_name SEPARATOR ';') item_name,
    sh.shelter_name, sh.url, st.status_st, st.status_md, st.status_end, st.status_last, st.photo  
                FROM shop_info s
                    LEFT JOIN shop_buyer b ON s.id = b.shop_id
                    LEFT JOIN shop_shelter sh ON s.id  = sh.shop_id 
                    LEFT JOIN shop_status st ON s.id  = st.shop_id 
                    LEFT JOIN shop_items it ON s.id  = it.shop_id 
                ORDER BY s.id
```

При таком расскладе, мне выводит только 1 строку в которой все товары. Надеюсь я понятно рассписал.

Помогите пожалуйста, совсем слаб в mysql

Comment: добавьте `group by` без него все группируется до одной строки

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!